# Android minimum exposure compensation

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, camera, hardware

In android camera i am able to set the exposure compensation  and lock the camera to minimum using the given methods

```
    params = mCamera.getParameters();
    params.setExposureCompensation(params.getMinExposureCompensation());
    params.setAutoExposureLock(true);
```

but still this is not the minimum exposure. In the program i do it by pointing the camera to a bright light source and then lock the camera exposure on click of a button. This is however not a good method. Is there any other way to reduce the exposure to absolute minimum?

Latest update : Ios 8 supports better minimum exposure compensation

Comment: This depends on camera-specific details. What is the value you get from `params.getMinExposureCompensation()`? What do you get in `params.getExposureCompensation()` after using the "bright light technique"?

Comment: I usually get the value of -4 on Samsung galaxy S2 and -12 on Nexus 5 ans Samsung s5 for minimum value but it doesn't turn the expusure to very dark.  After using the "bright light technique" it becomes totally dark and you would only see the light sources such as LEds in a normal light room .

Comment: You did not answer the question: What do you get in params.getExposureCompensation() after using the "bright light technique"?

Comment: it is -12 itself at that time as well . I tried setting values like below -12 but it doesnt help

Comment: So, the HAL caps the exposure values at **-12** even though the underlying level can skew the the actual exposure (or gain, or both) even lower.

Answer (score 0):

Both S5 and Nexus S use Qualcomm Snapdragon. You can find the code of its HAL in AOSP. You can modify this code to allow lower manual exposure levels. You don't even need to make changes on kernel level.

No, there is no easier way to do it - neither in Java nor using NDK.

I guess that using a torch the way you described it may be automated (let SW decide when to lock exposure, instead of a button), and will work for a wider range of devices, and don't need replacing system libraries.

Comment: I don't know about this , I will look into HAL in AOSP and code it.